# Hyperlink execution not possible in Excel 2010

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel-2010

Hyperlinks in Excel cells can be created but not executed.
Also, the VBA command `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` does not work any more.

I get the message:

> The operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

Even more strange: I now opened Outlook 2010 and tried to execute a hyperlink in a message I got.

I get the message:

> Your organization's policies are preventing you from completing this action for you. For more info, please contact your help desk

The strange thing is, this is my private PC, There is no administrator other then myself.

All Trust Centre settings seems to be OK.

Is there a known solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just disabled macros (aka VB) from running. Try re-saving the file as a macro-enabled file (I think it is suffixed .xlsm). Open the file, allow running macros, and it should work.